# Laravel loop where: Posts as post where post_user_id and and user_id match

Tags: laravel, foreach

as title says I want to make a loop foreach item where the post_user_id and user_id match, but just dont know quite how

```
@foreach($posts as $post where $post->user_id == auth()->user()->id)

@endforeach
```

There many posts with different post_user_id's but i want for a specific account to see all his own posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to do this logic in your blade file. Rather you should do it in your controller and just pass the variable to the view/blade file.

For example. In your controller:

```
// I'm assuming the name of your model is POST
$posts = Post::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->get();

// this will get all posts where the user_id is equal to the 
// id of the logged in user

return view('THE NAME OF YOUR VIEW FILE GOES HERE', compact('posts'));
```

Now in your view file you can just loop over this variable as normal:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
 ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I will try it thank you :)

Comment: @Memonik I made an error with a missing closing bracket. I have updated my answer with the fix.

Comment: Okay, I managed to get it working, only thing I needed to add to your code is ->get() otherwise i got no data back and also no error

So full working code is:
$userPosts = Post::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
        
        return view('userPosts',[
            'posts' => $userPosts,
            'categories'=> Category::all()
        ]);

Comment: Thanks for the info. That skipped my mind a bit. I'm updating it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$userPosts = Post::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
        
        return view('userPosts',[
            'posts' => $userPosts,
            'categories'=> Category::all()
        ]);
```

It receives all the data where the `user_id` and `post->user_id` matches and everything works.